# request.getRequestDispatcher() and context.getRequestDispatcher()

Tags: jsp

What is the main  difference in using request.getRequestDispatcher() and context.getRequestDispatcher()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In request.getRequestDispatcher(path) in order to create it we need to give the relative path of the resource. But in   resourcecontext.getRequestDispatcher(path) in order to create it we need to give the absolute path of the resource.